# Version management of binary files at githuh

Tags: github, binaryfiles

The Edit menu is not visible for uploaded binary files. How do I maintain versions of binary files in github?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do when you say "maintain"? Also, have you looked at Git LFS? https://git-lfs.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

File upload support is there for binary files.

Versions are stored by GitHub as new versions of the same fie are uploaded

[image]